# Move column to the third column position

Tags: r

I have two tables. In each of those two tables I've already moved a column to the first column position, using this command:

```
table1 <- 
  table1 %>%
  select(column1, everything())
```

Then I merged the two tables and tried to move a column from the second table to the beginning, using:

```
new_table <- 
  cbind(table1, table2) %>% 
  select(column2, everything())
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name
```

The cbind works just find without the select() function. It's just not possible to move column2 to the front. Is there a way to move it to the second column position? I struggle finding solution to this here on stackoverflow.

Another example that is reproducable:

```
iris1 <- 
  iris %>%
  rename(petal.test1 = Petal.Width) %>% 
  select(petal.test1, everything()) 

iris2 <- 
  iris %>%
  rename(petal.test2 = Petal.Width) %>% 
  select(petal.test2, everything()) 

iris_total <- 
  cbind(iris1, iris2) %>%
  select(petal.test2, everything())
```

Comment: Presumably you have `column2` in both tables. Using the example `cbind(iris,iris) %>% select(Species, everything())` you'll see you get this error because you have two columns with the same name

Comment: The tables definitely have different names, and so do the columns. Both column names and table names are unique.

Comment: The error you're getting explicitly states "some arguments have the same name". If that is not the case, please provide a reproducible example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: My above example reproduces your error, following an analogous process, and here we can fix it by enforcing unique names: `cbind(iris,iris) %>% as.tibble(.,.name_repair = "unique") %>% select(Species...5, everything())`

Comment: added a reproducable examaple, as requested. My code is slightly different from the one you posted before because I renamed the columns in order to avoid having the same column names twice. Still does not work.

Comment: It's not just that `petal.test` needs to be unique, all names need to be unique. By the way, the error is being thrown by `select`, not `cbind`. `select` fails because it doesn't know how to handle duplicate names, even when using `everything()`

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to do this in the first place.

Comment: With `cbind(iris1, iris2) %>% select(Species)`, `select` fails because `Species` is not unique. With `cbind(iris1, iris2) %>% select(everything())`, `select` fails because multiple column names are not unique.

Comment: @BroVic I have data from two different tables that I want to merge. In both tables I have different unique keys (in SQL you'd call them primary keys). I want to have the key from the first table next to the key from the second table to be able to visually see whether they are the same. This helps me to ensure that the data is merged correctly (that rows are connected correctly without jumps)

Comment: @shymilk you could just do a join instead...

Comment: `tidyverse` supports all standard join operations, `left_join`, `full_join`, `anti_join` etc. So does base R with `merge`

Comment: I know I shouldn't use the comment function to say thanks, but thanks. I'll try using join functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bind_cols` instead

```r
library(dplyr)

iris1 <- 
  iris %>%
  rename(petal.test1 = Petal.Width) %>% 
  select(petal.test1, everything()) 

iris2 <- 
  iris %>%
  rename(petal.test2 = Petal.Width) %>% 
  select(petal.test2, everything()) 

iris_total <- bind_cols(iris1, iris2) %>% 
  select(petal.test2, everything()) %>% 
  as.tbl()
iris_total
#> # A tibble: 150 x 10
#>    petal.test2 petal.test1 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Species
#>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1         0.2         0.2          5.1         3.5          1.4 setosa 
#>  2         0.2         0.2          4.9         3            1.4 setosa 
#>  3         0.2         0.2          4.7         3.2          1.3 setosa 
#>  4         0.2         0.2          4.6         3.1          1.5 setosa 
#>  5         0.2         0.2          5           3.6          1.4 setosa 
#>  6         0.4         0.4          5.4         3.9          1.7 setosa 
#>  7         0.3         0.3          4.6         3.4          1.4 setosa 
#>  8         0.2         0.2          5           3.4          1.5 setosa 
#>  9         0.2         0.2          4.4         2.9          1.4 setosa 
#> 10         0.1         0.1          4.9         3.1          1.5 setosa 
#> # ... with 140 more rows, and 4 more variables: Sepal.Length1 <dbl>,
#> #   Sepal.Width1 <dbl>, Petal.Length1 <dbl>, Species1 <fct>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Works perfectly.